# Address of global variables in x86 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, global-variables

I have a C code that declares global variable `char file[MAX]`. This variable is used in various functions directly to copy filename to it. I can compile this c file to assembly code but I don't know how to find the **address** of this variable?
 In x86 stack, how do I find the address of a global variable? Can you give me an example how global variable is referenced in assembly code?

EDIT: I don't see a .Data segment in the assembly code.

Comment: I think it will be in the BSS section, not DATA.

Comment: @Barmar Weird, I don't see this section too. I'm really confused.

Comment: What do you mean *In x86 stack*? It's not in (or on) the stack. You declare in your assembly, `extern file` and then you can access it. The symbol, `file`, will represent the address of the array. When you say, *I don't see a .Data segment in the assembly code*, what assembly code are you referring to?

Comment: `.comm` pseuido instruction may be used to allocate global variable initialzed to zero.

Answer (score 3):

To store the address of `file` to register EAX:

AT&T syntax: `movl $_file, %eax`

intel syntax: `mov  eax, OFFSET _file`

---

**How to examine:**

Firstly, write a simple code (`test.c`).

```
#define MAX 256

char file[MAX];

int main(void) {
    volatile char *address = file;
    return 0;
}
```

Then, compile it to asssembly code: `gcc -S -O0 -o test.s test.c`

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .comm   _file, 256, 5
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .text
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    $_file, 12(%esp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE0:
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.1"
```

Or if you want intel syntax: `gcc -S -O0 -masm=intel -o test_intel.s test.c`

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .comm   _file, 256, 5
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .text
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    push    ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    mov ebp, esp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    and esp, -16
    sub esp, 16
    call    ___main
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+12], OFFSET FLAT:_file
    mov eax, 0
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE0:
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.1"
```

With a little more experiments and examination, I got the result.

Comment: The Mac OS X ABI prepends `_` onto C symbol names, but Linux doesn't.  In Linux, `char file[]` in the asm will be `[file]`.  Or `file[rip]`.  See a trivial example on godbolt: http://goo.gl/ewwP2V

Comment: Just to be clear for the OP, the preceding underscore may or may not be there. On my Linux system, I get `file` rather than `_file`.

Comment: @PeterCordes asm will be `[file + rip]` in x64 mode and `[file]` in x86 mode. x64 addressing is relative, while x86 is not (at least as far as I can remember; it's been a while since I read about this). Some assemblers add an implicit instruction pointer offset when addressing statically allocated memory in x64 mode.

Comment: @BobbySacamano: That's correct, rip-relative addressing is not available outside 64bit mode, even on CPUs that do support 64bit mode.  And yes, `[file + rip]` is another way to write it.  I used `file[rip]` because that's the what the intel-syntax assembly output from gcc looks like on godbolt.  Also correct that `default rel` is the default in some assemblers, so `[file]` and `[rip+file]` mean the same thing sometimes.